SweetAlert2 CSP (style-src-elem) rror
I've got website that uses Sweetalert2 script.
CSP header is:
"style-src-elem 'self' fonts.googleapis.com *.jsdelivr.net"
Browser is sending me error:
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-elem 'self' fonts.googleapis.com *.jsdelivr.net".
I'm using nonce for implementing sweetalert script.
Is there any other solution except adding  unsafe-inline in CSP?
To be even more precize browser added errors in this lines of code
screenshoot from console
i've tried to add in CSP that CDN domain "*.jsdelivr.net"
